# Rails: Override RESTful paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

Is it possible to override a RESTful path?

For instance, I have `photo_path(photo)` which would generate `/photos/12345`

But I'd like for all uses of `photo_path` to actually generate URL's like `/photos/joeschmoe/12345` (which is the photo's user and the photo id).

Obviously I could just create a new route, but wanted to make sure there wasn't a more RESTful way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make photos a sub-resource to user's, so you'd have `users/joeschmoe/photos/12345` (of course here, your users controller would require the ability to accept a username instead of an id, which is another routing problem to solve but not difficult)

```
resources :users do
  resources :photos
end
```

Then your controller could maybe call

```
@photos = Photo.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

Although I think there are less hacky ways of doing that.

You could also add `joeschmoe` as a query string parameter.

Or you could make username an optional parameter in the route, so it would be something like

```
match "/photos(/:username)/:id" => "photos#show"
```

Or if you want a new named route:

```
match "/photos/:username/:id" => "photos#show_by_user", :as => :user_photo
```